# Am I an Irish citizen / eligible for Irish citizenship?

Tags: citizenship, ireland

I'm a Canadian citizen potentially relocating to the Czech Republic for a few months for my work and my employer is about to start the paperwork for a Czech visa but one thing I'm curious about... from what I hear from some people, I might be eligible for / actually already be an Irish citizen. If I am, wouldn't that would make the Czech visa process redundant as I could use my Irish citizenship to work in the Czech Republic?

I was born in Canada, and my father was also born in Canada. However, my father's mother was born in Northern Ireland in the 1930s (subsequently emigrated to Canada in the 1950s). Apparently Ireland doesn't care about Republic vs. Northern when granting citizenship, and it seems grandchildren of Irish citizens are eligible for Irish citizenship but the stuff I've read on the internet is kinda ambiguous and I'm not sure what applies to me. Further, I'm not sure how much paperwork/fees would be involved in the process of getting the citizenship, if I am eligible.

Comment: https://www.dfa.ie/passports-citizenship/citizenship/born-abroad/registering-a-foreign-birth/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are entitled to citizenship through descent, according to [Citizens Information](http://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/moving_country/irish_citizenship/irish_citizenship_through_birth_or_descent.html), which provides comprehensive information on public services and entitlements in Ireland.

> **Citizenship through descent from Irish grandparents**
>
> If one of your grandparents is an Irish citizen who was born in Ireland, but neither of your parents was born in Ireland, you may become an Irish citizen. You will need to have your birth registered in the Foreign Births Register – see below.

- Your grandmother was an Irish citizen, born on/before 31 December 2004
- Your father, her child, born outside of Ireland, is/was an Irish citizen
- You, as the child/grandchild, is entitled to Irish citizenship, but you must first register in the Foreign Births Register.

> **Foreign Births Register**
>
> If you wish to be included in the [Foreign Births Register](https://www.dfa.ie/passports-citizenship/citizenship/born-abroad/#) you must use the online application facility. You can find information about [making an online application, the documents required, the photographic requirements and the fees on the website of the Department of Foreign Affairs and Trade](https://www.dfa.ie/passports-citizenship/citizenship/born-abroad/registering-a-foreign-birth/).
>
> Once you have completed the online form you must send your printed application and required supporting documentation to the [Irish embassy or consulate for the country in which you live](https://www.dfa.ie/home/index.aspx?id=285).
>
> Once the process is completed, you will be provided with a certificate confirming your entry in the Irish Register of Foreign Births. This certificate can be used as proof of Irish citizenship when [applying for an Irish passport](http://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/travel_and_recreation/travel_abroad/passports/applying_for_or_renewing_an_irish_passport.html).
>
> Please note that Irish passport applications cannot be accepted at the same time as citizenship applications - these are 2 very distinct processes.

Fáilte roimh sa bhaile go hÉirinn !